# Overlay Each Bar of Stacked ggplot2 Barchart with Line

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, bar-chart, overlay

I have a stacked ggplot2 barchart, which looks as follows:

```
# Example data
data <- data.frame(level = rep(1:3, 3),
                   values = c(20, 30, 25, 15, 10, 5, 18, 20, 30),
                   group = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3)))

# Draw plot without lines
library("ggplot2")
my_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = level, y = values, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("A", "B", "C"),
                    values = c("forestgreen", "darkgoldenrod1", "brown2"))
my_plot
```

[image]

Now, I want to overlay each bar of this barchart with a blue line of a certain height. The blue lines should also be represented in the legend of the plot.

The data for these lines looks as follows:

```
# Data for lines
data_line <- data.frame(level = 1:3,
                        values = c(25, 40, 10),
                        group = as.factor("D"))
```

The output should look as follows (image drawn in paint):

[image]

**Question: How could I add these data as overlaying lines?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `geom_segment`

```
my_plot + 
  geom_segment(data = data_line, 
               aes(x = level - 0.45,
                   xend = level + 0.45,
                   y = values,
                   yend = values, 
                   col = "D"), # 'fake' a legend
               size = 2,
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL,
                     values = c(D = "#007fff")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1),
         color = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(t = -1, b = -15)) # trial and error
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! Is it possible to "merge" the two legends to one legend with the order A, B, C, D?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, now it's exactly as I wanted!